# Is there a way to add geotagged photos as a raster layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have several geotagged photos that I am trying to run an analysis on. I am trying to add them as a raster layer in QGIS. Even though they are not an orthomosaic, is it still possible to add them as a raster layer?

Here are some of the photos, [which can be downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h0xkmDg7jnzkCJEe8Mj2v91P9B2W-u41?usp=sharing) (download size: 34.2 MB):

The geotagged coordinates are the centroid of each photo, so I have been able to add them to the map as a point layer using the "import geotagged photos" tool:

[image]

However, I have not figured out a way to add them as a raster layer. Is there a way to physically add them into QGIS, and not just import their locations? If not QGIS, I am open to using another program to solve this problem if necessary.

Comment: check the georeferencer.

Comment: Your only option would be to georeference the images manually.  I have checked your test images with EXIFtool and your GoPro camera does not include the camera azimuth, pitch, roll, and yaw to automate the georeferencing as described here:  https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=linkedin_share&utm_medium=member_desktop_web

Comment: @GBG gdal could also be used, but with only a control point, the result won't be helpful.  A better option would be to stich everything together and use the points as GCP.

Comment: @Al rl  - there does not seem to be a zero order polynomial transformation option in GDAL that would allow for a single GCP. https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltransform.html.  Have you done this? If so, any code you could share would be helpful.

Comment: do you really want to import the images as raster or do you want to show the images in a preview when clicking on the vector point?

Comment: @Shawn I am trying to classify the images using object-based classification. I was hoping to do a supervised classification, hence why I am trying to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account that a raster is always an squared layer defined by an extension (x*y) and a cell size. There's no way to "import photos as raster", but QGIS has tools to transform those points into a raster.

## 1st method (squared points raster):

1. Transform you layer into a projected crs (this makes the following transformations more intuitive).
2. Rasterize. You can either asign a unique value for cells or asign a value from a parameter of the layer (for example the altitude). You can change the resolution to the value that match the final layout you are looking for.

[image]
[image]
[image]

## 2nd method (rounded points rasters):

1. Transform you layer into a projected crs (this makes the following transformations more intuitive).
2. Make a buffer of the points. In this case I measure the diameter it should has in the final layout.
3. Rasterize the buffer as in method 1. In this case, if you select a very tiny cell size you can imitate the dot simbology.

[image]

[image]

Good luck ¡